# Can anybody explain such behavior of accuracy and loss of my Net?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I used [this](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/) project for example(framework - caffe, arhitecture of net - mod of AlexNet, 400 images are used for training). I have this result:
[image]

or this:
[image]

Solver:

```
net: "./CDNet/Models/train.prototxt"
test_iter: 500
test_interval: 500
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 50
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "./CDNet/Models/Training/cdnet"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Model of net:
[image]

Can anybody explain such behavior of accuracy and loss of my Net? What I am doing wrong?

Author of tutorial has got this result: 
[image]

**UPD:**
I changed batch size from 1 to 12 and step sizw to 2000. Result is on picture below:
[image]

It is around 0.5 accuacy every test.

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the stepsize to ~2000?

Comment: step size is **orders of magnitude** to big

Comment: @greeness, yes, see a picture(**UPD**)

Comment: Can you describe your data a little more? how many training samples? how many validation? how many classes? what is the size of your model (approx. num of parameters)? Are you trying to fine-tune the entire model or just specific layer?

Comment: Can you further increase your batch size to 200 or 2000?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make a complete analysis without looking at *your* code and *your* data. Note that `0.5` accuracy for a binary classification is merely **a random guess**. You'll get the same result if the network outputs a constant and the test set is not skewed towards one class.

What is definitely seen from these charts is that the model is not learning. Since there's no training accuracy on your charts, I can't even tell if it's overfitting (I can't believe that enhanced AlexNet is underfitting).

As far as I can see, the task requires careful data preparation, and it's a probable step to make a mistake: check that your training and test data make sense (they should be 227x227, clearly recognizable for a human, also check the size of both sets). Double check the calculated mean image and preprocessing step. The hyperparameters look reasonable and are said to work for this dataset, so in general I would trust it.